# “victim to” and “victim of”

Tags: prepositions

In Insider Secrets To Hydraulics there is two texts:

1. > When I inquired why the new pump hab been fitted, the maintenance manager advised me that the original pump hab been uneconomical to repair. I knew immediately that this maintenance manager had fallen **victim to** distributor bias.
2. > There are three things you can do to ensure that you don't become **a victim of** one of these costly rip-offs.

In both texts "victim" is used in a similar sense but with different construction. Can you explaine to me why in 1) there is construction "victim to" and in 2) there is "victim of"?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps consult a dictionary?

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/victim) shows "fall victim to" as a standardized phrase.  Probably that (and variants) are the only time we use "to" with "victim".

Answer (score 0):

The common  construction is ***[fall victim to](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fall%20victim%20to)***, [fall victim of](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fall%20victim%20to%2Cfall%20victim%20of&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfall%20victim%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfall%20victim%20of%3B%2Cc0) is a less common variant. In both case the meaning is:

> : to be affected badly by (something)
>
> - She fell victim to the flu.
> - He fell victim to a scam.
> - schools falling victim to budget cuts
>     (M-W)